# How to use only conda installed packages?

Tags: python, conda

I want to use packages that were installed with conda. When I not use a conda environment the versions are messed up between system versions and conda versions. The best method to ensure the use of conda versions is to use a conda environment with `conda create`. However, `conda create` needs a list of packages e.g. "seaborn" and it builds an environment only with these packages and dependencies. Is there an option to add all packages to the environment?

Or does anyone know a better method to ensure that conda installed versions of python packages are used? Maybe using the PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Comment: You'll need to explain what you mean. What do you mean with adding *all* packages to an environment? If you simply want to create a default environment for yourself you always add that permanently to your `PATH` env variable. And then use that all the time. You can just to `conda create -n <env_name> python to create an environment with Python only.

Comment: I mean all packages that are currently installed with `conda install ...` while no environment is activated.

Comment: I think you're missing the key concepts of conda environments. Packages are installed always and only into environments. You create specific environments with the packages you want installed into them. If you do `conda install` without specifying an environment, it goes into conda's root environment. That's also an environment. Normally you want to keep the root environment as clean as possible with only conda + python installed into it. If you quickly want to be able to create environments with lots of packages installed, you should look into `conda env` (https://github.com/conda/conda-env).

Comment: Thanks for clarification! So the answer is to clone the root environment.  So using `conda create -n newEnv --clone root ` should do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You can't clone the root environment because conda is installed in the root environment and conda can only be installed in a root environment. Best thing would be to start from scratch, keep your root environment clean and start creating other new environment. Just create manually `environment.yml` files for each project you're working on and create an environment per project.

Comment: I think i worked though.